# Build dependencies with gradle, Android Studio, ADT

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, adt

I am developing Android app with gradle project.  My teammates use ADT, and I do Android Studio and I would like to try my best not to force limiting IDE for others.

As far as I know, ADT needs to have local dependencies (.jar or local lib).
Also if I have main project and local library which contains same local jar files, it cannot build with gradle due to "IllegalArgumentException: already added".

Settings below works fine with gradle and Android Studio but not for ADT, support v13 is not found.

Is there any way to make build works for gradle, Android Studio and ADT ?

Please let me know if you need more information.

My project setting looks like

**settings.gradle**

```
include: ':MyProj'
include: ':libs:PagerSlidingTabStrip'
```

**build.gradle (MyProj's)**

```
.....
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.+'
    compile project(':libs:PagerSlidingTabStrip')
}
.....
```

**build.gradle (PagerSlidingTabStrip's)**

```
.....
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.+'
}
.....
```

Comment: what do you mean by ADT , are you refering Eclipse ?where the code is not working in Eclipse or in AS ?

Comment: I think that in the particular case of Android, it will be difficult to support both the old (ADT/Ant) and new (Android Studio/Gradle) development environments at the same time. You might have to maintain them separately, or wait until the whole team is ready for the transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do the following:

- Make an Eclipse project for MyProject and libs/PagerSlidingTabStrip
- In MyProj, create a libs folder and dump in it both support-v13 and support-v4.

Do *NOT* change build.gradle to dep on the content of libs/ or you'll have a duplicate class file issue.

This is manageable if you have only one lib project and few dependencies. If your setup become more complex it'll become impossible to manage (hopefully by then we have Gradle support in Eclipse)

Comment: Thank you so much.  This worked !
Although dealing dependencies with external lib in gradle is cooler and making life easier,  for now, I hesitate to force teammates to switch their favorite IDE.  This is really a great help.